# get_by_id in google app engine python ndb responds with None

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm having trouble using `get_by_id` in google app engine python ndb.

**Python Code**

*Attempt 1*

```
resource = Content.get_by_id(6093630880088064)
```

resource is `None`

*Attempt 2*

```
resource = Content.get_by_id(6093630880088064, parent = 5249205949956096)
```

`BadValueError: Expected Key instance, got 5249205949956096L`

*Attempt 3*

```
key_parent = ndb.Key('Subject', '5249205949956096')
resource = Content.get_by_id(6093630880088064, parent = key_parent)
```

resource is `None`

**Datastore**

```
Entity Kind       Content
Entity Key        ahBkZXZ-YnJhaW5ib290ZWNocigLEgdTdWJqZWN0GICAgICAxKkJDAsSB0NvbnRlbnQYgICAgIDE6QoM
ID                6093630880088064
Parent            ahBkZXZ-YnJhaW5ib290ZWNochQLEgdTdWJqZWN0GICAgICAxKkJDA
Subject:id=5249205949956096
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. My goal is that resource will be an object where I can do something like `resource.name` to retrieve the name property.

Comment: if item have `parent` key then `get_by_id` must hava `parent` param

Answer (score 11):

This problem occur when you have the key as string, the simplest solution is:

```
Model.get_by_id(int(id))
```

This problem is most likely to appear is when you read the id from url and the like:

```
class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, id):
        instance = Model.get_by_id(int(id))
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved :)

```
key = int(key)
key_parent = ndb.Key(Subject, 5249205949956096)
resource = Content.get_by_id(key, parent = key_parent)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Attempt 1:**
You get None because no instance exists with this ID. Either the ID is wrong or it's a string not an integer like you’re passing to the function.

**Attempt 2:**
get_by_id actually expects the parent before the ID (if the parent is passed). If you wanna keep that order then use

```
resource = Content.get_by_id(id = 6093630880088064, parent = parent_key)
```

More importantly, the parent argument is the key of the parent not its ID.

**Attempt 3:**
In your code the ID of the parent is passed as a string and that of the content is passed as an integer. I'm guessing that the problem lies there. You pass either as strings of integers.

Hope that helps.